# Cross Filter - Filter on Groups (Top N groups)

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I personally found cross filter very powerful as it re calculates on the fly filters which are done on dimensions. However, is it possible to achieve something  similar to the **HAVING** clause in SQL via crossfilter, out of the box? Or should this be done manually?

I have already achieved the following:

```
          Total Points
Team A0      100
Team A1      50
Team A2      120
Team A3      10
```

I would like to show in a dc.js visualisation the TOP 3 teams only. The above groups should then be recalculated when I filter on another dimension (e.g. date), such that different teams show up on the visualisation.

Comment: I think the dc.js `cap` functionality is what you are looking for: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.capMixin+cap